# Get the jquery select2 plugin to work on appended form

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 plugin with an ajax call to get a select box using a hidden field.
On my page i have an add button which adds another select box into the page.
I am trying to get the select2 plugin to work on this inserted field.
i have tried with a 'on' method as well..

```
$('.selectcateg').on('load',function(){
   $('.selectcateg).select2({
   minimumInputLength: 2,
   ajax: {
      url: "../../../datafeeds/categorylist.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
      return {
          q: term
      };
   },
     results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data };
     }
   }
});
});
```

But that way stop it working even on the field that is loaded originally. If i remove the 'on' function it does not work on the added content.

This is the basic code I am using to append to my form..

```
$('#catgeoryform').append('<input type="hidden" name="category[]" class="selectcateg">');
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think after 5 hrs after different attempts I have got it working.

Ive had to use a callback on an event to fire the select plugin. Im sure there is an easier way round this but its working so I am happy.

I slide the add button up, append the information, slidedown the new input box and then call the function..

And it adds the select2 box to the hidden input..